# can't build a link between unbound forms

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have two tables in my database, `Person` and `Action`.  `Person` has a one-to-many relationship with `Action`.

I'm trying to build a `Main` form that has a `Person` form and an `Action` form on it, so that when an entry for `Person` is clicked on, the corresponding entries in `Action` show up in the `Action` subform.

But when I view `Main` in Design mode, and  click 'Link Master Fields' in the properties for the `Action` subform, I get this error message:

```
Can't build a link between unbound forms.
```

How can I set up this master/child relationship?

Comment: Does `Main` have a record source set?

Comment: @Brad: No.  `Main` is just a blank form that I dropped the `Person` and `Action` subforms onto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only link form which have data bound to them. Really I suspect you want your `Action` form to be a subform of `Person` not for both of them to be sibling child forms of a "main" form.

Comment: Ok, but I have some buttons on `Main` to search for records in `Person`.  Also, I just set the record source of `Main` to `Person`, which allowed me to set the Master/Child of Person.ID to Action.PersonID, but the recordset of the `Action` form doesn't update when I click on a different record in `Person`.

Comment: Never mind, I got it to work.  I added a hidden text field on `Main` that has [Person].Form!ID as its Control Source, and called this hidden field `ID`.  That caused the `Action` recordset to update properly.

Answer (score 8):

I know this thread is two years old but, as I was facing the same issue, I found that it actually **is possible** to link two unbound forms.

The trick is simply to input the master and child fields manually in Design mode *without* lauching the MS Access 'Link Master Fields' routine.

For example, I used the following to link two unbound forms on two separate criteria:

```
Master fields: tsObjectID;obObjectID [;etc.]
Child fields: tsObjectID;obPackagingUnitID [;etc.]
```

Comment: This worked for me. Put the form in design view, and then just manually type in your maser/child fields.